# DDD - Is creating logically dependant aggregate roots that don't make sense on their own a bad practice

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm developing real-time chat functionality as part of an application. As per my initial structure I had 3 Domain Objects as part of this new context:

- `Thread` (aggregate root)
- `ThreadMessage` (entity, part of the `Thread aggregate` as a collection; has a ParticipantId to know it's sender)
- `ThreadParticipant` (entity, part of the `Thread aggregate` as a collection)

The problem arose when I realised I need the `Thread` and `ThreadParticipant` relationship to be logically (and in the persistance store) many-to-many. My `User` (from the Identity bounded context) will hold a reference to a `ThreadParticipant`'s ID.

The more I thought the less sense it made for the `ThreadParticipant` to be a child entity in `Thread` as it it can obviously live on it's own being in a many-to-many relationship with `Thread`.

My question is is it bad to create a separate bounded context with `ThreadParticipant` as the aggregate root, which will hold a collection of `Thread` IDs, for example. And if so, what will happen to the `Message` entity from the `Thread` aggregate root- it will hold a reference to the `Participant` aggregate root which will cause a circular reference between both contexts.

Comment: Don't confuse aggregate roots with database records; they're not the same thing.  This probably all belongs in a single root.

Comment: I know that the persistance is a detail that should not interfere and the domain should not care about. Could you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: It's a chat program, not an enterprise system.  Your aggregate root is essentially `void main()`

Comment: It's not a chat program, I don't think I've stated that anywhere. Chat functionality is just a component

Comment: Well, regardless, the chat system is a module.  If you want to call it an aggregate root, that's fine, but that's as fine-grained as I think you need.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I get what you're saying now. I'd like it as simple as it can get, but I am concerned with the creation of new `ThreadParticipant`s as I think they must be created outside of the `Thread` factory.

Comment: Why do you think the DDD tactical patterns are a good way to solve this problem? DDD is about solving complex *business* logic. A bounded context with chat functionality can be technically complex, but is not likely to contain much business logic.

Comment: You are right, I think I get what you're saying. Are you implying that this chat module should not be a separate bounded context at all?

Comment: It should be a separate bounded context. Part of DDD is identifying the core domain that deserves the most attention and identify supporting and generic sub domains that are not all that important. A chat application, for most businesses, is not critically important and businesses often decide not to spend costly developer time on it and simply buy it off the shelf.

Comment: But let’s disregard that and go ahead with building the application. If there are no real business problems to solve, and the challenges for building the application are technical, the DDD *tactical* patterns (aggregates, entities, etc.) are often not required to solve the problems at hand.

Comment: So, if there's no complex business rules to be followed, the chat module is better of as an infrastructure concern?

Comment: Aggregate roots exist to protect their invariants. What kind of invariants does you `Thread` have over the collections of messages and participants, so that the two collections must be part of the `Thread` directly?

Comment: _"Could you elaborate on your comment?"_ Not OP, but very basically put, a `Car` in your domain (aggregate) may be stored in the database spread out over many different tables (`Car`, `Tires`, `MaintenanceHistory`, `AccidentHistory`), but that does not mean that your domain has to individually acknowledge all these tables as individual aggregates. The domain and the datalayer choose their own structure, for their own reasons.

Answer (score 1):

There are no issues in having a many-to-many relationship between Theads an Participants. The decision is not about the relationship but instead about the consistency that you want to enforce.

- Should you be able to retrieve all threads and look at their participants?
- Should you be able to retrieve all participants and look all their thread?
- given a participant, should you be able to access all threads info even if a thread as been deleted?
- given a thread, if a partcipant changes its nickname after joining, should  you still be able to watch old nickname into thread participants list?

well these are the questions that make you understand if thread and participants are two different aggregates. If so, they should be as loosely coupled as possible

Final note about bunded context: as of now, we've talked about information consistency and we have used aggregates to define boundaries around those consistent information. Bounded Context are not the same as aggregates. Aggregates enforce logical consistency, bounded context enforce semantic consistency. You could have multiple aggregates in a bounded context, but each aggregate has its unique meaning in this context. You've choose to have "Users" and "Participants" into your application. Well, it's clear that a Participants IS a user, but in the identity BC, being a user means to be identified in the system, in chat BC being a users means interact with other users. So, same concept, different meaning, but you're still interested on keeping some form of consistency between the two BCs